# How to use PyDict_SetDefault with regard to the refence count of default

Tags: python, dictionary, python-c-api

I'm wondering about how to use [`PyDict_SetDefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/dict.html#c.PyDict_SetDefault) without creating a reference count catastrophe.

The documentation doesn't say anything about a stolen reference and some testing shows that it doesn't "steal the reference" of `default`. But it increfs it *if and only if* the key wasn't present in the dictionary.

That seems really complicated to me because it's just too easy to get wrong. I currently use it like this:

```c
item = PyDict_SetDefault(dictionary, key, defaultvalue);
if (item != defaultvalue) {
    /* key was present, the item is a borrowed reference and default is at refcount 1.*/
    Py_INCREF(item);         /* item at refcount 2 */
    Py_DECREF(defaultvalue); /* default at refcount 0 */
    defaultvalue= NULL;
} else {
    /* key wasn't present, item is default and has refcount 2. */
    defaultvalue = NULL;
}
```

At the end the dictionary and I own a reference for `item` and `default` was cleanly deleted, right?

Is there a better way to deal with the situation without explicitly checking if `item == default` that I missed? Is it really that complicated or did I miss the *obvious and easy* way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
item = PyDict_SetDefault(dictionary, key, defaultvalue);
Py_INCREF(item);
Py_DECREF(defaultvalue);
```

It doesn't really matter whether `item==defaultvalue` - whatever happens you take ownership of `item` (by increfing it) and release ownership of `defaultvalue` (by decrefing it, assuming you don't want to use it for anything else).

if `key` is present in the dictionary then `defaultvalue` isn't used, so its refcount stays at 1, and it gets destroyed with decref. `item` is returned with a refcount of 1 (because it's stored in the dictionary) and we increment it because we're using it too so `item` now has a refcount of 2.

If `key` isn't present then `defaultvalue` is stored in the dictionary (refcount now 2) used and returned. `item` and `defaultvalue`  are the same. We increment `item` (refcount 3) the decref `defaultvalue` (refcount 2).

Either way we end in the same place.